# Set programmatically papersize to A4 in CrystalReports viewer

Tags: crystal-reports

what I see in CrystalReports designer differs from what I see in CrystalReports viewer when I load a report programmatically. This is because in the designer I chnaged papersize to A4, while in the viewer it is Letter by default.

So, how can I change *in code* (c#) default paper size to A4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewer follows system settings (paper size for default printer).
You can change paper size for underlaying report programmatically (report object PaperSize property); does it affect viewer defaults, I don't know.

Our application changes paper size only for specific printers (POS ones), but it changes report default printer too and in that case viewer follows printer and paper size settings. CR version 9 - maybe later versions are more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found out the PaperSize property and it does work!